# Consider: $f(t)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}\, dx=\frac{1}{t}, t>0$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> > Show that the function
> >     $$
> > f(t)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}\, dx=\frac{1}{t}, t>0
> > $$
> >     can be differentiated indefinit times under the integral and use this to show the formula
> >     $$
> > \int\limits_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}\, dx=n!
> > $$

Hello, my problem is to show

1) that $f$ can be differentiated under the integral. Is this an improper parameter integral? What do I have to show?

2) that $f$ can be differentiated under the integral indefinit times.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use dominated convergence theorem on
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{g(x,t_n) - g(x,t)}{t_n - t}
$$
where $g(x,t) = e^{-tx}$. Find an $L^1$ function $h(x)$ such that
$$
|\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t)| \leq h(x) \quad \forall t
$$
(Hint: $e^{-tx} \leq e^{-x}$ for all $t \geq 1$) From this you will see that
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \int_0^{\infty} -xe^{-tx}dx = \frac{-1}{t^2}
$$
Now repeat the process inductively and plug in $t=1$.

Bartle's book on Measure Theory has a very nice section on "integration w.r.t. a parameter" which might be worth a read.

Comment: For $t\geq 1$ it is $h(x)=e^{-x}\cdot x$. But whats with $0<t<1$?

Comment: Since the other answer was deleted I'll post it here -  
Look at xe^-tx (think about its behaviour), and then, for a given t, choose the x that maximises its modulus (it will be a function of t, and you will need a bit of differentiation). Then you'll have your answer :)

Comment: I got $h(x)=\exp(-t^2)t$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: Sorry, thats wrong ;( I dont know.

Comment: Maybe you mean $e^{-1}/t$? But is this integrable?

Comment: $h_t(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{e^{-1}}{t}, & 0<t<1\\xe^{-x}, & t\geq 1\end{cases}$

Comment: Sorry I was away, you're on the right track, I'll write up an answer for you shortly :)

Comment: Another question. Why not simply using $h(x):=e^{-tx}\cdot x$? I calculated $\int_0^{\infty}h(x)\, dx=0<\infty$.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. I hadn't thought about this correctly. The differentiation of e^-tx wrt to t will not occur at t=0, since you are told that t>0, so assume it occurs at some point t1 > 0. Then, you can form a closed interval containing t1, call it [a,b], with a>0. Then you get xe^-tx < xe^-ax, and your dominated convergence. :)

Comment: The key is that you only need to justify the differentiation under the integral sign at a given point t, not for all points t simultaneously. So if you look at @Prahlad's answer, and change the hint to e^-tx <= e^-ax for all x > 0, the logic follows. You might have been thrown off when you read for all t>=1. All he means here is if you choose a t>=1, e^-x will do the job. He could easily have said choose a t>0 and find a such that 0<a<t. Then e^-ax will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to use the monotone convergence theorem, since

$g_n(x,t)=\frac{g(x,t) - g(x,t_n)}{t-t_n}\leq\frac{g(x,t) - g(x,t_{n+1})}{t-t_{n+1}}=g_{n+1}(x,t)$

where $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb R$ is an increasing sequence such that $t_n\rightarrow t>0$. Note that $g_n\nearrow\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$ and consequently (M.C.T.):

$$-\frac{1}{t^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^\infty g_n(x,t)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t) \,dx = -\int_0^\infty xe^{-tx}dx$$

will be necessary to conclude using induction and plug in $t=1$.